# How to cascade update 2 tables whose foreign key is not set to cascade?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got 2 tables. They have a foreign key relation. But the foreign key is not set to update cascade. Now I want to update the table's primary key. SQL Server always prevent me from doing that because of the FK. How could I do it in SQL command? I don't have the right to modify the FK.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't - you need to change the FK, disable the FK and re-enable it afterwards, or not perform the update. There aren't any deferred constraint checking options in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? It strikes me as potentially hazardous. 
Your SQL would need to update the related table first NULLing the links back to the PK table and storing the IDs of the records effected. Then you can update the PK in the PK table. Then go back and update the FKs in the related tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create new rows based on the existing row's attribute values but using the new key value. Do the same for all referencing tables. Then, using the new old key value, delete rows from the referencing tables then the referenced table. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (key_col, attrib_col1) 
   SELECT 'new_key_value',  attrib_col1
     FROM Table1 
    WHERE key_col = 'old_key_value';

INSERT INTO Table2 (key_col, attrib_col2) 
   SELECT 'new_key_value',  attrib_col2
     FROM Table2 
    WHERE key_col = 'old_key_value';

DELETE 
  FROM Table2
 WHERE key_col = 'old_key_value';

DELETE 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE key_col = 'old_key_value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to INSERT new rows for the parent table and UPDATE the child rows after the fact...

```
INSERT INTO ParentTable (PKColumn, attribute1, attribute2)
    SELECT 'NewPKValue', attribute1, attribute2
    FROM   ParentTable
    WHERE  PKColumn = 'OldPKValue'
;


UPDATE ChildTable
SET    FKColumn = 'NewPKValue' 
WHERE  FKColumn = 'OldPKValue'
;


DELETE
FROM   ParentTable
WHERE  PKColumn = 'OldPKValue'
;
```

Now for the gotchas:

1.) The above code wont work if there are any unique indexes defined on non-PK columns in the parent table and you need to use the current records' non-PK data values without modification.

2.) Since you're asking this question, I'm assuming your Parent table is not using an IDENTITY column as the PK.

3.) The code is certainly less than efficient. If your db has to do this infrequently on a few rows, you should be fine. If you need to do this 80 times per second, then I would strongly suggest you talk to the programmer/DBA or vendor, if they're at all available, about updating the FK definition to include ON UPDATE CASCADE.

4.) Make sure that there aren't any triggers on either table that would lead to unintended side effects when you create the new parent records or update the child records.